# follow embedded link with spring traverson HAL

Tags: rest, spring-hateoas

I can follow the links with spring traveson HAL library, I wonder if is there any way that I can follow an embedded link as well.

for example, I can follow `someLink` with `traverson.follow("someLink")` but I am looking for a way to follow `someResource` `self` link.

```
{
  "name": "some name",
  "_embedded": {
    "someResource": [
      {
        "name": "some resource name",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://someEmbeddedUrl"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "someLink": {
      "href": "http://someUrl"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `PagedResources<Resource<SomeResource>>`. Take a look at the following example (`SomeResource` is a POJO):

```
Traverson.TraversalBuilder tb = traverson.follow("someLink");
ParameterizedTypeReference<PagedResources<Resource<SomeResource>>> typeRefDevices = new ParameterizedTypeReference<PagedResources<Resource<SomeResource>>>() {};
Resources<Resource<SomeResource>> resources = tb.toObject(typeRefDevices);
Resource<SomeResource> firstItem = resources.getContent().iterator().next();
firstItem.getLinks().forEach(l -> {
    System.out.println(String.format("rel: %s href: %s", l.getRel(), l.getHref()));
});
```

For your example, this snippet should print `rel: self href: http://someEmbeddedUrl`